# Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I'm trying to store images using `mongoose`, `express`, `multer` but when I test with postman it always gives the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined

```
var express=require("express")
var  router= express.Router();
var app=express()
var artisanModel=require("../models/artisanModel")
var fs = require('fs')
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest: __dirname + '/uploads/images'});

router.post('/add', upload.single('image'), function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.file.originalname)
  var file = __dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.originalname;
  fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
    fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        var response = {
          message: 'Sorry, file couldn\'t be uploaded.',
          filename: req.file.originalname
        };
      } else {
        response = {
          message: 'File uploaded successfully',
          filename: req.file.originalname
        };


        artisan = new artisanModel({
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password,
          tel: req.body.tel,
          image:  req.file.originalname

        })

        artisan.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            res.send({'State': 'Not Ok', 'msg': 'err' + err})
          }
          else {
            res.send({'State': 'Okay', 'msg': 'added'})
          }
        });
      }``
    });
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

//model

```
//Require Mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


//Define a schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var artisanModelSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {type:String,
    trim:true,
    required:false},

  lastName : {
    type:    String,
    trim:true,
    required:false},
  tel : {
    type:    String,
    trim:true,
    required:false},
  adresse: {
    type:    String,
    trim:true,
    required:false},
  password: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: false
  },
  imagee:
    { dataa: Buffer, contentType: String , path : String }



});
var artisanModel=mongoose.model('artisanModel',artisanModelSchema);
module.exports=artisanModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

pls check the multer documentation it will not process any form which is not multipart (multipart/form-data).

```
NOTE: Multer will not process any form which is not multipart (multipart/form-data).
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Check the second line in the above link.

**EDIT**

Please upload the images using postman changing the body type into form-data and upload the image. Refer the screenshot.[image: here]

Comment: solution ?  @sundaram

Comment: you should upload it using html code only
```<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="text-center">
  <input type="file" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".xlsx">
</form>``` [check this](https://shiya.io/simple-file-upload-with-express-js-and-formidable-in-node-js/)